# Enable silverlight on the site

Tags: windows, firefox, browser, internet-explorer, silverlight

I was working with regexp on the site that works on silverlight. When I finished and wanted to copy final regexp, system asked me if I want to allow this app to write in my buffer. I automaticly clicked the left button ("yes" button is the left button by default as far as my UX says), but in this time it was "no" button. It blocked silverlight and now when I click `ctrl+c` site says that it cannot access buffer.

How can it be fixed? I thinked that it's FF issue, but on IE I get the same error

Comment: Try going to firefox > addons > plugins > Silverlight. Can you change the setting to "Ask to Activate"?

Comment: yes, it's in "always active"

Comment: So did that fix the blocking of Silverlight?

Comment: I did it before asking, so no.

Comment: OK. I don't have another suggestion at the moment, except maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling Silverlight.

Comment: One more thing to check. Open the problem page in firefox. Goto Page Info (ctrl+shift+p). Select the "permissions tab". You should be able to override the silverlight settings there.

Comment: @DavidPostill in my case it opens private window, not settings.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution, but cannot say that is was obvious. Right-click on silverlight app, select "Silverlight" option in menu, you will enter into `Microsoft Silverlight configuration`, then `Permissions` tab, change `denied` on `allowed`. Screenshot is below, sorry for non-english language, cannot change it for this screenshot.

[image]